# Word for someone who agrees with everything to avoid conflicts

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for a word to describe someone who always agrees with everyone and everything (like boss, teacher, parents, friends) just to avoid conflicts and discussion. The person in question never even tries to discuss and even when someone treats them unfairly they would never complain about it.

Already thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is an innate characteristic and I do not have a good translation for that.

However, to the outside world they will look like a **pushover** regardless of why they are doing this.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pushover

> someone who is easily persuaded or influenced or defeated

Answer (score 1):

Another term is simply **conflict-avoidant** . I think that 'pushover' has a more negative connotation, so if you were trying to describe this more neutrally I would use

> conflict-avoidant

or, similarly, **conflict-averse**

As in

> My co-worker is very conflict-avoidant, so it can be difficult to get his real opinion about the problems we are having on the project.

Answer (score 0):

Some other terms with negative connotations are **doormat**, **sycophant**, **yes-man**.

A nicer way to describe a person like this is non-confrontational.